# Error when attempting to call an index from a list in python

Tags: python, for-loop

i'm trying to make a function that will print the data_sets[51] from this huge list. However when I try to run it i get a error:

```
line 460, in paste_up
for items in sublist[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My function paste_up looks like this:

```
# Paste the sheets onto the billboard as per the provided data set
def paste_up(data):
   for sublist in data_sets:
       for items in sublist[1]:
        if item[0] == 'Sheet A':
            Sheet_A( item[1], item[2])
        elif item[0] == 'Sheet B':
            Sheet_B( item[1], item[2])
        elif item[0] == 'Sheet C':
            Sheet_C( item[1], item[2])
        elif item[0] == 'Sheet D':
            Sheet_D( item[1], item[2])
```

the list i'm trying to test with is:

```
['X', ['Sheet A', 'Location 1', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet B', 'Location 2', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet C', 'Location 3', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet D', 'Location 4', 'Upright']],
```

Any help would be appreciated.

edit.....
Having issues with the function now endlessly drawing the images that i was trying to get to print. Here is an example of my function that draws a 200x500 rectangle at a specific location.

```
#draw the Sheets and the images on them.
def Sheet_A(location, orientation):
    #code for location and orientation of Sheet_A.
    if location == 'location 1':
        if orientation == 'upright': goto(-300,0);setheading(0)
        elif orientation == 'upside down': goto(-300,0);setheading(180)

    elif location == 'location 2':
        if orientation == 'upright':goto(-100,0);setheading(0)
        elif orientation =='upside down': goto(-100,0);setheading(180)

    elif location == 'location 3':
        if orientation == 'upright':goto(100,0);setheading(0)
        elif orientation == 'Upside down':goto(100,0);setheading(180)

    elif location == 'location 4':    
        if orientation == 'upright':goto(300,0);setheading(0)
        elif orientation == 'Upside down':goto(300,0);setheading(180)

    #drawing Sheet_A outline and filling the background.
    width(3);penup();begin_fill();forward(100);pendown();right(90)
    forward(250);right(90);forward(200);right(90);forward(500);right(90)
    forward(200);right(90);forward(250);color('blue');end_fill();color('black');penup()
```

Comment: If `for items in sublist[1]` give you an `IndexError`, then `sublist` has at most 1 element

Answer (score 0):

First of all change `for items...` into `for item...`

And this is what your code should look like:

```
for sublist in data_sets:
    for item in sublist[1:]:
        if item[0] == 'Sheet A':
            Sheet_A( item[1], item[2])
        elif item[0] == 'Sheet B':
            Sheet_B( item[1], item[2])
        elif item[0] == 'Sheet C':
            Sheet_C( item[1], item[2])
        elif item[0] == 'Sheet D':
            Sheet_D( item[1], item[2])
```

It should work if your data looks like this:

```
data_sets = [['X',
  ['Sheet A', 'Location 1', 'Upright'],
  ['Sheet B', 'Location 2', 'Upright'],
  ['Sheet C', 'Location 3', 'Upright'],
  ['Sheet D', 'Location 4', 'Upright']]]
```

Comment: then `print "DEBUG sublist :\n\type : {}\n\tlen : {}"` just after the line `for sublist in data_sets:` is your friend :)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've gotten it to print, however the turtle graphics I was using it for is endlessly drawing the images I've made, and its ignoring the co-ordinates.

Comment: oups, I forgot to mention the format method for the printed debug string... my bad.
`print "DEBUG sublist :\n\type : {}\n\tlen : {}".format(type(substring),len(substring))` or even better, instead of it make a try: / except IndexError: statement...

Comment: I've added a function that uses the Paste_up function in an edit under the original code.  This all involves using turtle graphics and i'm quite losT.